# Template behavior depends on actual class of an instance in a class hierarchy

Tags: django, django-templates

In django I have a model A and 3 derived models D1, D2, D3. I also have a ManyToManyField in another model B that references instances of A that can be instances of D1s, D2s or D3s. In the template, if I loop over the instances of A referenced by the ManyToManyField of B. How can I distinguish the display according to whether the actual model of my As is D1, D2 or D3? And how can I access a field which is in D1, but not in A, D2 or D3 when the actual class of my instance is D1?

Comment: Can you share the Django models (so as class definitions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward way in *vanilla* Django to obtain `Di` objects from a queryset that targets the `A` model. You can use [**`django-polymorphic`** package <sup>[pypi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-polymorphic/) which will make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s on all submodels of `A` and then, depending on which table has a hit, return an object that is a `Di`.

You can also do what `django-polymorphic` does, by working with a `.select_related` and then "specialize" the object, so if we have a `B` model object `b`, we can work with:

```
a_objects = b.a_set.select_related('d1', 'd2', 'd3')
```

and then inspect this with:

```
for a in a_objects:
    d1 = getattr(a, 'd1', None)
    if d1 is not None:
        print(d1.field_of_d1)
```

This will thus then return a `D1` object if it is a `D1`  object, and then we can print a `field_of_d1` object.

This will of course produce more complicated queries and hence increase the load on the database. Using inheritance/polymorphism when storing data in the database is often *not* a good idea since relational databases don't turn out to work out with inheritance.

Comment: Awesome, the django-polymorphic package works as expected from your post! Thanks ;)